# Associate Same Mdb java class to multiple queue in Ejb3 jboss 5.x server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss5.x

```
 package jboss5.ejb3.mdb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="queue/Queue1"),
    }
    )

@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@EJB(name = "EJB3MessageDrivenLocal1", beanInterface = EJB3MessageDrivenLocal.class)

 public class EJB3MessageDrivenBean implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener
 {
ObjectMessage msg = null;
private MessageDrivenContext mdc = null;

public EJB3MessageDrivenBean() {}

public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext mdc) {
    this.mdc = mdc;
}

public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        }

@Override
public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
 }
```

Above code is my message driven bean and working fine for single queue 'Queue1'. Now i want to associate Queue2 to same mdb.
I can do the same thing by creating another mdb class "EJB3MessageDrivenBean2" and by just changing activationConfig property as follow.

```
    @MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="queue/Queue2"),
    }
    )
```

but in this method i have to replicate my code and in future if i have to associate another queue Queue3 then i have to again replicate java file.

Any other method by changing in xml file or any other method.

MORE DETAILS

Lets say message in queue1 are JmsMsg11,JmsMsg12,JmsMsg13,JmsMsg14
Lets say message in queue2 are JmsMsg21,JmsMsg22,JmsMsg23,JmsMsg24

I have to process JmsMsg11 and JmsMsg21 simultaneously. After processing of JmsMsg11, i have to process JmsMsg12 then JmsMsg13 then JmsMsg14. Same is also applicable for queue2.

I have done same thing in weblogic 10.x by some change in ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml by following code. dont know how to do in jboss 5.x.
ejb-jar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB1</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>jboss5.ejb3.mdb.EJB3MessageDrivenBean</ejb-class>
      <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
  <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

<activation-config>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            DestinationType
        </activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>
            javax.jms.Queue
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            DestinationJndiName
        </activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>
           Queue1
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            ConnectionFactoryJndiName
        </activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>
            QFact1
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
   </activation-config>
 </message-driven>
     <message-driven>
       <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB2</ejb-name>
       <ejb-class>jboss5.ejb3.mdb.EJB3MessageDrivenBean</ejb-class>
       <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
       <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

   <activation-config>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            DestinationType
        </activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>
            javax.jms.Queue
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            DestinationJndiName
        </activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>
           Queue2
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>
            ConnectionFactoryJndiName
        </activation-config-property-name> 
        <activation-config-property-value>
            QFact2
        </activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
     </activation-config>
   </message-driven>
 </enterprise-beans>

   <assembly-descriptor>
        <container-transaction>
          <method>
             <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB1</ejb-name>
             <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
         </method>
  <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>

<container-transaction>
  <method>
    <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB2</ejb-name>
    <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
  </method>
  <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
</container-transaction>
```

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE weblogic-ejb-jar PUBLIC '-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD WebLogic 8.1.0 EJB//EN' 'http://www.bea.com/servers/wls810/dtd/weblogic-ejb-jar.dtd'>


   <!-- Generated XML! -->

   <weblogic-ejb-jar>
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
      <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB1</ejb-name>
        <message-driven-descriptor>
         <pool>
        <max-beans-in-free-pool>1</max-beans-in-free-pool>
         </pool>

       <destination-jndi-name>Queue1</destination-jndi-name>
    </message-driven-descriptor>

      <transaction-descriptor>
    <trans-timeout-seconds>600</trans-timeout-seconds>
     </transaction-descriptor>

  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>

  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
     <ejb-name>WeblogicEjb3MDB2</ejb-name>
       <message-driven-descriptor>
         <pool>
        <max-beans-in-free-pool>1</max-beans-in-free-pool>
         </pool>
       <destination-jndi-name>Queue2</destination-jndi-name>
      </message-driven-descriptor>

     <transaction-descriptor>
    <trans-timeout-seconds>600</trans-timeout-seconds>
     </transaction-descriptor>

  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
 </weblogic-ejb-jar>
```